# Facebook canvas app unable to get access token using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

Good Noon,

I am trying to create new facebook canvas app. Facebook app tried to get access token from `getCanvasHelper()` method, but every time I tried to print it shows blank.  I am using PHP SDK 5.0.0

```
$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

Here below is the full sample code. Due to access token issue I am unable to process further.

Any help would be appreciable.

Here below is my sample code.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'my_app_id_i_have_replce_it_for_security',
  'app_secret' => 'my_app_secret_i_have_replce_it_for_security',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

$permissions = ['user_posts']; // optionnal

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // validating the access token
    try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/bs-kapil-canvas/', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // getting all posts published by user
    try {
        $posts_request = $fb->get('/me/posts?limit=500');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $total_posts = array();
    $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge();
    if($fb->next($posts_response)) {
        $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
        $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
        while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response)) {  
            $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
            $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);  
        }
        print_r($total_posts);
    } else {
        $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
        print_r($posts_response);
    }

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/bs-kapil-canvas/', $permissions);
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can use your canvas address as the redirect URI; I think you might be losing the parameters in that case. Try pointing it to the URL where your app is hosted, and see if that changes anything. Plus, inside canvas you should consider using the JS SDK for login, instead of the redirect version - makes for a much nicer user experience.

Comment: Every thing is fine. After a long research found that fascebook only works with HTTPS else it will send blank response.